# Yocto Kirkstone not able to package library .so in rootFS

Tags: yocto, recipe

I'm having some problem creating a simple recipe for yocto which make and install a library .so file to rootFS, possibily in /usr/lib or /lib.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Personal Libwakeup Library"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "gitsm://xxxx.git;protocol=https;branch=master"

# Last revision in branch master.
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

# out-of-tree building doesn't appear to work for this package.
B = "${S}"

PACKAGECONFIG ??= ""

FILES:${PN} += " \
    ${libdir}/libwakeup_handling.so \
    ${libdir}/libwakeup_handling.so \
    /lib/libwakeup/libwakeup_handling.so \
"

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"
INSANE_SKIP:${PN} = "ldflags"
INSANE_SKIP:${PN}-dev = "ldflags"

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "all"

do_compile:prepend() {
   (cd ${S}/Debug && oe_runmake)
}

do_install:append() {
 # Here I have to put "--target-directory=${D}${libdir}/libwakeup" instead of --target-directory=${D}${libdir} otherwise doesn't works. 
 install -Dm 0644 --target-directory=${D}${libdir}/libwakeup    ${B}/Debug/libwakeup_handling.so
 
 # To resove QA issue...
 cd ${D}/usr/lib && ln -s -f libwakeup_handling.so.1.0.0 libwakeup_handling.so
 cd ${D}/usr/lib && ln -s -f libwakeup_handling.so.1.0.0 libwakeup_handling.so.1

}
```

So seems I can't place a library .so directly in /lib or /usr/lib.
Moreover the file I found in /usr/lib/libwakeup folder is only 9.5kB instead of 150kB of the library Yocto make during do_compile() phase.

Answer (score 1):

Your target directory does not line up w/ what is in `FILES_PN`. Should be `${libdir}/libwakeup/libwakeup_handling.so` instead of `/lib/libwakeup/libwakeup_handling.so`.

Furthermore, your symlink changing is not going to work, because `libwakeup_handling.so` is in `${libdir}/libwakeup` not `${libdir}`.